# selecting similar values in mysql (some thing, sömé thińg, some-thing, some¤thing should be the same)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a tagging system and I need to retrieve similar tags, so when a user would punch in "some thing" or "somé thing" or "söme thing" or "some¤thing" etc he would get all the matching rows in the table.

If I were using `utf8_general` or `utf8_unicode` on the field, it would be a piece o' cake. I could just

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE 'some thing'
```

but alas, I need to use `utf8_bin` in that table. So, what do I do? I'm not a very big mysql expert. I think I should be using CAST() or CONVERT() but I'm not sure how.

The second part, getting the some-thing, some*thing, some&thing etc, is another issue, but I think I can solve it on my own with Regular Expressions

EDIT: **THE SOLUTION**
I thought that messing around with all this converting and regexping might not be the best way. Instead, I will use my framework's methods and generate a URL "name" of given tag and store it on the same db row.

Comment: Is this going to be used i non-english languages? Beware that those "decorations" carry meaning. In Swedish "far" means father while "får" means sheep. I do care quite a lot if my daughter calls me "far" or "får" ;-)

Comment: using your example, the idea is that when a user goes to domain.com/tag/far he would be able to see items that are marked with either far or får. and yes, it's a non-english site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the convert :-

```
mysql> select convert( "söme thing" using utf8) = 
convert( "some thing" using utf8);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| convert( "söme thing" using utf8) = convert( "some thing" using utf8)  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                      1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I think is no benefits to use utf8_bin

When handling search of tag, you can consider to store

- clean version (some)
- an additional table to map söme and other variations to the clean version
- when user search for söme, is possible for you to look-up söme = some

Comment: There are benefits. The problem with utf8_general is, is that a and ä are the same, so goes with any other similar letters. as for your code, I'm not really sure how to use it. I'll try it out when I'll get the chance, thanks for contributing!

Comment: You are storing data in utf8 binary while looking a matching in utf8 general, would not that be strange?

Comment: haha ...that's why I say you are strange. If you want a utf general feature, then store into utf general instead of looking a workaround

Comment: yes, but with utf general, adding stuff into database with given task is impossible, since it treats a and ä the same. so I can't check if user is inserting already existing tag when it has far or får. and both carry different meanings

Comment: If both represent two different meanings, what is the point of this question ?(which you are looking for a = å), you might need to re-think the storing process

Comment: because they both need to be accessed from the same url. that's the the point. I can't use numerical tag ids, it needs to be human readable

Comment: Yup,input are usually fat.You SHOULD store something into the tag, whilst link all the variances like sömething to something. When using enter "sömething" is possible to link to something. Maybe I added that into answer

Comment: you got me thinking, thanks!

for the solution, I will generate url with every tag so I can later on just use WHERE tag_url = 'something'