# Levenshtein implementation with PHP and database

Tags: php, database, search, levenshtein-distance

I have a search form. If the user makes a typo like `ager` instead of `anger`, it should still show the relevant results instead of displaying 0 results found.

I came across the [PHP levenshtein function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) and the example that they have given with array is exactly what I want [except that the user can input a sentence rather than one word], but I would like to implement it with database, but have no idea as to how go about implementing it with database.

This is my code:

```
if(!empty($search))
{
    try {
        $query = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        if(!$query->rowCount()==0)
        {
            $foundRows = $this->_db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $cQuote =  $this->highlightWords(htmlspecialchars($row['cQuotes']),$search);
                $search_result[] = array('success' => true, 'totalRows' => $foundRows, 'cQuotes' => $cQuote, 'vAuthor' => $this->h($row['vAuthor']), 'vBookName' => $this->h($row['vBookName']), 'vRef' => $this->h($row['vRef']));
            }
            $response = json_encode($search_result);
            echo $response;
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $ex =  "No results found for " .$search;
            $this->errorMsg($ex);
        }
        $query->closeCursor();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex){
        $ex =  "Problem: " .$ex;
        $this->errorMsg($ex);
    }
}
else
{
    $ex =  "Please enter something";
    $this->errorMsg($ex);
}
```

I should add that I'm using MySQL + PDO.

Comment: Are you looking for something like google suggestion? IMO, i prefer to return zero matches, then suggest other possible terms

Comment: @ajreal, Not really. I have one entry in the database with two different spellings. When the user types in the keyword with one spelling, I want that it displays all the results relevant to that term regardless of the different spellings. For example, `Andy` and `Andi` should return all the results containing both the terms, even if the user has typed `Andi`.

Comment: :-s then you might as well store the synonyms, so either andy or andi can reference each other

Comment: @ajreal, sorry for this noob q but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I have answered a similar question before (about the same as what you are looking for, in my thinking) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374312/selecting-similar-values-in-mysql-some-thing-some-thing-some-thing-somethin/8374350#8374350 (read the lengthy comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, you'd need three things:

- [A Levenshtein-distance implementation on the MySQL end](http://joshdrew.com/)
- An index of words found in each text
- Split the search query into words, a `LEFT JOIN` for each word and an `HAVING` clause

An example database schema:

**text**

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| text_id | text                                         |
+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|       1 | The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  |
|       2 | The slow brown foxes jump over the lazy dogs |
+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**word**

```
+-------+---------+
| word  | text_id |
+-------+---------+
| fox   |       1 |
| foxes |       2 |
| dog   |       1 |
| dogs  |       2 |
+-------+---------+
```

Once you have that, say someone searches for "`foxs dogg`", you'd build a query like this one:

```
SELECT text FROM text
    LEFT JOIN word w1 ON w1.text_id = text.text_id AND LEVENSHTEIN(w1.word, "foxs") < 3
    LEFT JOIN word w2 ON w2.text_id = text.text_id AND LEVENSHTEIN(w2.word, "dogg") < 3
    GROUP BY text.text_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

...where:

- Each word has a `LEFT JOIN` (e.g.: `foxs` and `dogg`)
- You have an `HAVING` clause that contains the total number of words (e.g.: `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`)
- The maximum distance for each word is specified (e.g.: `LEVENSHTEIN(...) < 3`)

The above would return both entries.

Here's another example:

```
SELECT text FROM text
    LEFT JOIN word w1 ON w1.text_id = text.text_id AND LEVENSHTEIN(w1.word, "foxs") < 3
    LEFT JOIN word w2 ON w2.text_id = text.text_id AND LEVENSHTEIN(w2.word, "slows") < 3
    GROUP BY text.text_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The above would return only `text_id = 2`.

Now, before you go crazy implementing this, you should know that multiple JOIN clauses, like the above, on a table having millions of entries (words), will have *a very big performance impact*.

**While this is a working example, you really should look for an already implemented search algorithm, like [Solr's SpellCheck](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) component.**

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply. My website is hosted by godaddy, and apparently it's refusing to let me create functions. As for solr, I don't think I will be able to install on a shared hosting.